# Why doesn't following code give any output , not even any error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using countdown jquery to display clock and timing it so as to use it for timing an exam . but I don't see any clock and neither so I see any error in javascript. Also I tried using alerts but it did not show any.

`

```
$( function () {
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: <?php echo $_SESSION['diff']; ?>, compact:true, onTick: warnUser});

    function warnUser(periods) {

        if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) == 2) {

            alert("it's working fantasticaly well");

            $(document).ready(function(){

                var test_id = document.getElementById('test_id').value;
                var test = document.getElementById('test').value;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "inc/maintest_times_up.php",
                        data: {
                        test_id: test_id,
                        test_name: test
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: "post",
                     beforeSend: function (json)
                          {
                         $("#model").addClass("load1");
                          },
                        success: function(json){
                         $("#model").removeClass("load1");
                            if (json['alert']) {
                             alert(json['alert']);
                            window.location.href="Feedback-test.php";
                                }
                        }
                        error: function  (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                          $("#error").html(jqXHR.responseText);
                        }

                    });
                return false;

            });
        }
    }
});
```

`

I have also used following in head of html :

```
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="error" style="border: solid 3px black; padding:5px;"></div>
```

and following css:

```
#defaultCountdown { width: 210px; height: 35px;  font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #B70000;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    }



 .load1 {
display:    block;
position:   fixed;
z-index:    1000;
top:        0;
left:       0;
height:     100%;
width:      100%;
background: url("../images/loading.gif") no-repeat 40% 40% #fff;
opacity: 0.7;
}
```

I have edited and updated the script tags , yet no response is generated .

Update 1: Here is the associated jquery.countdown.css

```
/* jQuery Countdown styles 1.6.2. */
        .hasCountdown {

                height:45px;
                width:210px;

        }
        .countdown_rtl {
            direction: rtl;
        }
        .countdown_holding span {
            color: #888;
        }
        .countdown_row {
            clear: both;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 12px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .countdown_show1 .countdown_section {
            width: 98%;
        }
        .countdown_show2 .countdown_section {
            width: 48%;
        }
        .countdown_show3 .countdown_section {
            width: 32.5%;
        }
        .countdown_show4 .countdown_section {
            width: 24.5%;
        }
        .countdown_show5 .countdown_section {
            width: 19.5%;
        }
        .countdown_show6 .countdown_section {
            width: 16.25%;
        }
        .countdown_show7 .countdown_section {
            width: 14%;
        }
        .countdown_section {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            font-size: 65%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .countdown_amount {
            font-size: 200%;
        }
        .countdown_descr {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

and

jquery.countdown.js contains code from following source . (Its quite large so I have paste of it [Pastebin link for jquery code](http://pastebin.com/V0NHAE3F))

```
/* http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html
```

Countdown for jQuery v1.6.2.
   Written by Keith Wood (kbwood{at}iinet.com.au) January 2008.
   Available under the MIT (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE.txt) license. 
   Please attribute the author if you use it. */

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` inside `$( function () {` is redundant - not a problem, just redundant

Comment: You have to call your script after jquery library.

Comment: without knowing what `.countdown` is (some jqueery plugin no doubt) or what the `<?php ... ?>` blocks actually are in the rendered HTML, can't tell why it doesn't work

Comment: what @alirezasafian may be trying to say is, the three script blocks in the head are in **exactly** the reverse order they should be

Comment: I tried above method of arranging the above script tags in reverse order and removing redundant code , still it does not work , please can someone point out why there is no error , and neither does it show a clock .

Comment: I have a feeling that the countdown script is fine, it's how you execute it. Do you know how to use jsfiddle.net. for testing and sharing?

Comment: @luke_mclachlan yes I also know that jquery.countdown is right as it is a very commonly used  and I tried using countdown timer in jsfiddle too here it is (it displays no output) [link](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=JSguSufkfs)

Comment: the fiddle doesn't show any code, it redirects me to a blank fiddle.